# fixed css header with special width

Tags: html, css, header, fixed

hello stackoverflow community,

i have a problem with my fixed header. my html structur looks like that:

```
<div id="site_wrapper">
<div id="site_header">Header</div>
</div>
```

The CSS Looks like this:

```
div#site_wrapper {
max-width:1500px; min-width:900px;
}

div#site_header {
            position:fixed; left:50%; top:0px; z-index:10;
            height:160px; width:1500px;
            margin-left:-750px;
            background-color:#fff;
}
```

My Problem is, that i need the header centered and fixed with the width 1500 ...

Some Ideas?

Comment: So what exactly does not work? What goes wrong?

Comment: what is the issue??? as per your code whatever you want its seems, its  working! See: http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/B2Tnj/

Answer (score 0):

To have a fixed header just use the following code:

```
div#site_header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: read question title: "fixed css header with **special width**"

Answer (score 0):

Since #site_header is inside site_wrapper you need to center #site_wrapper div, i also update the #site_wrapper code to be always centered inside #site_wrapper

```
        div#site_wrapper {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        max-width:1500px; min-width:900px;
```

}

```
        div#site_header {
        position: fixed;
        top:0px;
        z-index:10;
        height:160px; width:1500px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#fff;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the header fixed, center align and some special width, try updating you CSS code with below:

```
div#site_wrapper {
    max-width:1500px;
    min-width:900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#site_header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    height:160px;
    width:1500px;
    background-color:#ffff00;
}
```

Refer this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/B2Tnj/**

Hope this helps!